# ping command in bash shows heart character

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

Why am I seeing a heart `♥` after the ping command?  I'm running the command below over an ssh connection in ConEmu, if that changes anything. Is this expected or have I been hacked in some fashion? Pinging on other shells, non-Ubuntu shells, (git-bash) doesn't do this.

```
$> ping mail.google.com
PING googlemail.l.google.com (74.125.196.18) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from yk-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.196.18): icmp_req=1 ttl=46 time=0.991 ms
64 bytes from yk-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.196.18): icmp_req=2 ttl=46 time=1.00 ms
64 bytes from yk-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.196.18): icmp_req=3 ttl=46 time=0.993 ms
64 bytes from yk-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.196.18): icmp_req=4 ttl=46 time=1.06 ms
64 bytes from yk-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.196.18): icmp_req=5 ttl=46 time=0.957 ms
64 bytes from yk-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.196.18): icmp_req=6 ttl=46 time=1.04 ms
64 bytes from yk-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.196.18): icmp_req=7 ttl=46 time=1.01 ms
♥
--- googlemail.l.google.com ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.957/1.008/1.064/0.050 ms
```

Comment: It's probably a mistranslation (by the console) of the `Ctrl-C` sequence that you used to interrupt the ping command - try playing with ConEmu's encoding settings (you probably want UTF-8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm running the command ... in ConEmu, if that changes anything.

It changes everything. That's how your terminal emulator renders the character that's send for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> ([End-of-text](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/ascii.7.html), or `ETX`, hexdecimal `0x03`). You can try this out with `printf '\x03'`. Switch to another if you find it annoying, but I don't know if any emulators in Windows don't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

﻿You've mixed all up.

ConEmu is a terminal but not a shell.
git-bash is a shell.
ssh is a console tool providing remote connection.

(Local) terminal is a tool that just displaying output of running console applications (shells and other tools).

So, it's irregularly to compare ConEmu with git-bash. They are different type of tools.
What shell are you running in ConEmu? That is the question!

But if you observe that behaviour when you run ConEmu `->` git-bash `->` ssh `->` ping `->` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>,
that means that the bug (if you thing so) belongs to your ssh client because it (and only it) shows/types/prints that
character to the Windows console.

To be sure, compare your ssh behavior from

a) plain console: <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> `->` "sh.exe -l -i" `->` ssh and so on...

b) and from ConEmu: <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> `->` "ConEmu -basic -cmd sh.exe -l -i" `->` ssh and so on...